# How AWS SQS works for message delivery from queue to client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I can't find information about communication internals between AWS SQS queue and a client. What a model is used in order to delivery the message from SQS queue to client - push or pull ?

Does the SQS client need to continuously pull the SQS queue in order to retrieve  messages or messages are pushed from SQS to client in a some way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What a model is used in order to delivery the message from SQS queue
>   to client - push or pull ?

Pull

> Does the SQS client need to continuously pull the SQS queue in order
>   to retrieve messages or messages are pushed from SQS to client in a
>   some way ?

The client needs to continuously pull from the queue.

Comment: This is correct, of course, although to those unfamiliar with the long polling implementation of SQS, it doesn't necessarily show the complete picture.  The polling need not be done "continuously," like a spin loop -- long polling emulates a push -- listening full time to a queue that is empty requires only requires 3 HTTP requests per minute with a long poll timer of the max 20 seconds, and new messages arrive nearly instantaneously at the consumer if dropped into the queue in the middle of an otherwise-idle long poll request.